# How Test with Jest a function in the method "mounted" VueJS

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I would to try call a function already mocked. I use vueJS for the frond and Jest as unit test. Below a example of my code. My purpose is to test the call of « anotherFunction". The first test is succeed , not the second.Thanks for help or suggestion

code vueJS:

```
   mounted() {
          this.myfunction();
    }
    methods: {
          myfunction() {
              this.anotherFunction();
          }
   }
```

Jest code:

```
describe('Home.vue', () => {
   let wrapper = null;

   const options = {
       mocks: {
           $t: () => 'some specific text',
       },
       methods: {
           myFunction: jest.fn(),
       },
   };

   it('Should renders Home Component', () => {
       // Given        
       wrapper = shallowMount(Home, options);
       // Then
       expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
   });

   it('Should call anotherFunction', async (done) => {
       // Given
       wrapper.vm.anotherFunction = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([]);
       // When
       await wrapper.vm.myFunction();
       // THIS THE PROBLEM, myFunction is mocked and I can't call the function 'anotherFunction' inside...
       // Then
       // expect(wrapper.vm.anotherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });

});
```

Comment: You have to mock anotherFunction only and test if the myFunction call calls your mocked anotherFunction.

Comment: Can you give me a example ? If I remove the line ```methods: { myFunction: jest.fn() }```I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Comment: I use sinon to mock and verify so cannot give you an exact example. Can you show stacktrace of this error?

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

      at VueComponent.mappedAction (node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.common.js:937:20)
      at VueComponent.searchAdvertisements (src/components/ListJobs.vue:792:14)
      at VueComponent.created (src/components/ListJobs.vue:778:14)
      at invokeWithErrorHandling (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1850:57)
      at callHook (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4201:7)
      at VueComponent.Vue._init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4983:5)
      at new VueComponent```

Comment: In this stacktrace, searchAdvertisements is the name of "myFunction'

Comment: Is the anotherFunction the mapped action from Vuex Store?

Comment: Yes, but I mock the call with this: ```wrapper.vm.anotherFunction = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([]);```

Comment: look at these examples https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html

Comment: almost what I want. anotherFunction is mocked and I don't care what result of that function is. I want to know when it was called when I call myfunction().

Comment: As in the above exmples link you should create localVue and also create store wuth mocked action

Comment: Thank @Anatoly, I resolved my case ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finding a good way to help you if this test case. So, I thought in something like the chuck code below:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('Home', () => {
  
  it('method calls test case', () => {
     const anotherMethodMock = jest.fn();

    wrapper = mount(Home, {
      methods: {
        anotherMethod: anotherMethodMock
      }
    });
    
    expect(anotherMethodMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But, the Jest threw the following exception:

`[vue-test-utils]: overwriting methods via the methods property is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. There is no  clear migration path for the`methods `property - Vue does not support arbitrarily replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex m ethod extract it from the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests.`

I had the following insight, maybe, in this case, should be better to test the side effect of this `anotherMethod` calling. What does it change? Is something being shown to the user?

I believe that here we have started from the wrong concept.

I hope that this tip could be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Vinícius Alonso, We should avoid using `methods` and `setMethods` in our test cases because of it's [deprecation](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setmethods). But you can still test the `mounted` lifecycle by mocking the functions that are being called during mount. So you can do something similar to below snippet.

```
describe('Mounted Lifecycle', () => {
    const mockMethodOne = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.methods, 'methodOne');
    const mockMethodTwo = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.methods, 'methodTwo');

    it('Validate data and function call during mount', () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);

        expect(mockMethodOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(mockMethodTwo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

Do `mount/shallowMount` inside `it` only rather putting it outside of it as it was not working in my case. You can checkout [more details](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/148) on it if you want.